# How populate a Google Maps info window from a Dart app

Tags: google-maps, dart, dart-polymer, web-component

I'm working on a Dart app that heavily relies on Google Maps. How does/should one populate a Google Maps info window from within a Dart app?

Four approaches come to mind: Dart string interpolation (the string being HTML code), "templating" or web components or Polymer or...

The prototype (snippets below) does nothing more than placing "foo bar" in the info window.

**My Marker class**

```dart
var markerOptions = new JsObject.jsify({...});
_marker = GoogleMapsApi.newMarker(markerOptions);

GoogleMapsApi.getEventContext().callMethod('addListener', [_marker, 'click', (event) {
  map.openInfoWindow(_marker, 'foo bar');
}]);
```

**My Map class**

```dart
openInfoWindow(JsObject marker, String content){
  _infoWindow.callMethod('setContent', [content]);
  _infoWindow.callMethod('open', [map, marker]);
}
```

Sidenote: `GoogleMapsApi` is my own helper class dealing with Google Maps JavaScript interop, I plan to replace it with [Dart Google Maps](https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps).

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map (and search for _google-map_ at customelements.io.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but I don't see yet how I could combine the two (i.e. my Dart code and this component).

Comment: The question stated “How does/should one populate a Google Maps info window from within a Dart app?” so the answer “You might want to use _this_ Polymer component for that” is fine, especially taking into account that [Dart home page](https://www.dartlang.org/) is explicitly hinting you to do so. “How would I integrate it” is IMHO other question, apparently being an off-topic here on SO.